# Why is the Benetar floating in space without engine power?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In one of the opening scenes to *Avengers: Endgame* the Benetar is floating in space without engines working.

How is this?  Peter Quill Star-lord flew the Benetar to Thanos' planet to confront him.  It appears to still be space worthy, since Stark and Nebula leave (Thanos' home planet) after the Snapocalypse.

Why not just activate the engines to a jump-port and get somewhere instead of just deep space with no food, no water, etc?

Answer (score 4):

## No Fuel/Power

It's clearly stated in the movie that they have run out of power &/or fuel.

As such, they can't travel **by any means** let alone "jump".

Comment: So Star Lord had no plans for getting off Titan once the battle was done?  Seems like Nebula would've realized that the ship was low on fuel and they should head to nearest place first, possibly exact opposite heading of earth...

Comment: We don't know where the *Benetar* was actually heading (although Earth seems likliest) but regardless, they ran out.

Comment: I *think* Tony says that the fuel cells (or whatever he called them) were damaged during the fight with Thanos, which is why they ended up with no power. If the original plan to take the Infinity Gauntlet away from Thanos on Titan had succeeded (i.e. they hadn't actually fought him) it's they likely would have been fine for fuel.

Comment: "the fuel cells were cracked during battle and we figured out a way to reverse the iron [sic] charge, bought ourselves about 48 hours of flight time. Uh, but it's now dead in the water." https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4154796/quotes/